# LinearLayout with 2 textviews added dynamically with alignment problem

Tags: android, android-layout

I have lists of LinearLayouts with horizontal orientation each one containing two textviews added dynamically.
This LinearLayout is finally wrapped into master LinearLayout.

I want the second textview of each linear layout to be right aligned progrmatically. How can I do this dynamically.

Here's sample code:

```
LinearLayout placeHolderLinearLayout =  (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listhosts);

//Several such layouts with 2 text views will be added to placeholder
LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
l.setClickable(true);

TextView h = new TextView(this);
h.setText("left");
h.setSingleLine(true);


TextView t = new TextView(this);
t.setText("right");
t.setSingleLine(true);

l.addview(h);
l.addview(t);

placeHolderLinearLayout.addView(l);
```

There is android:layout_alignParentRight attribute. But how to set this dynamically in this case. Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `android:layout_alignParentRight` can only be applied to a view if its parent is a `RelativeLayout`. Change your container to that, and the 2 sub-views can use any of the `layout_alignParent*` attributes.

If you can't do this programatically (which I can't see how to do quickly), then you could always define your inner layout in xml (where you can easily get the layout correct) and inflate manually via:

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View l = vi.inflate(R.layout.inner_relative_layout, null);

TextView leftTextView = (TextView) l.findViewById(R.id.left_text);
leftTextView.setText("left");
// ... fill in right text too

placeHolderLinearLayout.addView(l);
```

Edit: added layout definition

Use a layout like this, and inflate it in the code as above:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/inner_relative_layout" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/left_text" android_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/right_text" android_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You will be creating multiple of these layouts for each item you're adding to your list.

Comment: Hi markf, Thanks for reply, I can change the placeholder to RelativeLayout.I have this much control only.

<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/listhosts"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/addHost" android:layout_weight="1">
</RelativeLayout>
But texts view I am adding to LinearLayout dynamically with some random ids. Now how can I align these two texts to extreme left and right of listview. Sorry I am not very clear about your solution. Can you elaborate a bit.

Comment: @Rakesh I've updated my answer to add an example layout. You can put all your layout in this file and inflate it several times as you need for each row in your list.

Comment: I just wanted to update you that I could achieve the same on LinearLayout as well. :-) Thanks for help

Comment: I have a small question: can `layout_alignParentRight` be used for 2 views in a liniar layout ?

Answer (score 1):

this one is woking and simple answer::

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView text[];
    TextView texto[];
    CheckBox check[];

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View view = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        text = new TextView[5];
        texto = new TextView[5];
        check = new CheckBox[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            text[i] = new TextView(this);
            text[i].setText("First one is::" + i);
            texto[i] = new TextView(this);
            texto[i].setText("sennd one ibs::" + i);
            check[i] = new CheckBox(this);

            ((ViewGroup) view).addView(check[i]);
            ((ViewGroup) view).addView(text[i]);
            ((ViewGroup) view).addView(texto[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below

```
LinearLayout placeHolderLinearLayout =  (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listhosts);

//Several such layouts with 2 text views will be added to placeholder
LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
l.setClickable(true);

TextView h = new TextView(this);
txt1.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
h.setText("left");
h.setSingleLine(true);


TextView t = new TextView(this);
txt1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
t.setText("right");
t.setSingleLine(true);

l.addview(h);
l.addview(t);

placeHolderLinearLayout.addView(l);
```

Comment: Hi Nik, Thanks for reply. whats txt1 here? I did 
h.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
t.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
and this is not working for me. :-(